# MatLab filter design vs. Python

Tags: python, matlab, filter, scipy, highpass-filter

I'm working on converting a MatLab code to Python and I see that they are not very compatible, so I have to use some new parameters on the Python side to be able to get the same results as MatLab. Still, there is a filter that I've tried hard to achieve the same result: fdesign.highpass and design in MatLab:

```
    hp = fdesign.highpass('N, Fc',order, FC, Fs);
    Hd = design(hp,'butter');
    Data(n,:)=filtfilt(Hd.sosMatrix,Hd.ScaleValues,Data(n,:));
```

I'm using `signal.butter` on the Python side but I couldn't get the same filter:

```
    b, a = signal.butter(10, FC, 'highpass', analog=False, 
fs=config.sampling_rate, output="ba")
    data7 = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data6)
```

Do you have any idea what the equivalence of the code given in Python is?

- Order = 10
- FC = 10
- Sampling frequency = 256
- Hd.sosMatrix :

> 1.0000   -2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   -1.8690    0.9268;
> 1.0000   -2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   -1.7473    0.8013;
> 1.0000   -2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   -1.6556    0.7068;
> 1.0000   -2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   -1.5948    0.6441;
> 1.0000   -2.0000    1.0000    1.0000   -1.5646    0.6129;

- Hd.ScaleValues:

> 0.9489;
> 0.8872;
> 0.8406;
> 0.8097;
> 0.7944;
> 1.0000;

- b:

> [   0.4551791    -4.55179104   20.48305968  -54.62149247   95.58761182
> -114.70513418   95.58761182  -54.62149247   20.48305968   -4.55179104
> 0.4551791 ]

- a:

> [   1.           -8.43131806   32.09602996  -72.63325918  108.1914843
> -110.82458397   79.0501498   -38.76564753   12.50684932   -2.39689227
> 0.20718802]

- Data used in both MatLab and Python:

> [-4.52524570e-04 -4.15547277e-04 -3.69618477e-04 -3.54294378e-04
> -3.49118638e-04 -3.32459161e-04 -2.81526419e-04 -2.27654353e-04
> -1.99580728e-04 -1.95510797e-04 -1.61056741e-04 -1.11072974e-04
> -5.32648681e-05 -2.46667403e-05 -5.41950912e-06 -2.31557119e-08
> 4.65967628e-05  1.15442535e-04  1.45564054e-04  1.41258639e-04
> 1.42186569e-04  1.86131459e-04  2.58602602e-04  2.98376655e-04
> 2.91488956e-04  2.84846883e-04  3.28808363e-04  4.04729607e-04
> 4.05485650e-04  3.03873916e-04  1.87973179e-04]

- Result in MatLab:
  [image]
- Result in Python:
  [image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: *"I'm using `signal.butter` on the Python side but I couldn't get the same filter."*  Show the Python code, and show the filter coefficients that you get.  Note that the SOS representation of a given filter is not unique, and you shouldn't expect the coefficients generated by SciPy and Matlab to be the same.  To do the comparison, check the actual frequency response, or try converting to the zeros-poles-gain or transfer-functon (i.e. "ba") representations in both SciPy and Matlab.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser question updated according to your answer.

Comment: @display_name although it is quite slow, have you thought of using the [MATLAB engine for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)? I used it before when I wanted to use a MATLAB toolbox that was difficult to replicate in Python, perhaps you could try that (assuming you still have access to MATLAB ofc)

Comment: @JamesT, I think I'll take your advice for some pieces of code that I can't convert, even though it's quite slow as you mentioned and I'm looking for good performance.... Thanks a lot for your suggestion! :)